# Можно ли значение по умолчанию в dict.setdefault() сделать функцией от ключа?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Известная возможность словарей Python - на лету подставлять значение по умолчанию для несуществующего ключа при помощи метода `dict.setdefault()` порою бывает весьма продуктивна. Ну например, вам нужно посчитать сумму чего то с одинаковым ключем, и лень накручивать `if ... else`.

У меня немного другая задача.  Есть необходимость поддерживать словарь подключений разных клиентов к Amazon.

Хотелось бы, чтобы была возможность устанавливать:

```
conn = dict()
conn.setdefault(connect_to)
```

где `connect_to` будет не константой, а функцией от ключа, для которого создается "значение по умолчанию".  Получится своего рода кеш подключений, для которого можно использовать все плюшки словарей типа итерирования или проверки на наличие ключа в словаре.

Наверняка есть такой модуль? То есть желаемый код будет примерно таким:

```
def connect_to(client_id_key):
    """Connect to Amazon by token."""
    ...
    return connection


conn = dict()
# обращение к словарю соединений либо создает соединение если такой ключ еще не в словаре
# или берет соединение из словаря как из кеша
x = conn.setdefault(task.client_id, connect_to(task.client_id))
x.get_report(...)
```

Здесь подразумевается, что есть поток задач на разных клиентов, который надо последовательно обрабатывать. Последнюю строчку кода привел просто для "материализации" вопроса, чтобы вопрос не казался надуманным.

Что скажете? Мне не хочется каждый раз вызывать функцию подключения, ведь иногда подключение уже есть.

Прикол в том, что вторая часть (наш `default`) всегда вычисляется, а я этого не хочу. Так код

```
conn = dict()
conn.setdefault(3, print("ключ был=",3))
conn.setdefault(3, print("ключ был=",3))
```

выдает

```
ключ был= 3
ключ был= 3
```

Хотя после первого `conn.setdefault(3, print("ключ был=",3))` в словаре уже есть ключ "3".   Можно сказать, что все, что мне хочется, чтобы метод .setdefault() был ленивым и *не вычислял* значение  `default`, а сразу лез в словарь, если ключ уже есть.

Наверное у меня словарь синглтонов.
Я конечно смотрел на `defaultdict` из модуля **collections**, но пока не сообразил как сделать то, что мне хочется.

```
from collections import defaultdict
conn = defaultdict(connect_to)
```

не работает как я хочу, т.к. если я передаю свою функцию как **default_factory**, то мне нужен отсутствующий ключ как параметр этой фабрики, а это не предусмотрено в `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант:

```
In [192]: def f():
     ...:     n = randint(0, 100)
     ...:     print(f"calling [f()], result {n}")
     ...:     return n
     ...: 

In [193]: conn = dict()

In [194]: conn.get(3) or conn.setdefault(3, f())
calling [f()], result 49
Out[194]: 49

In [195]: conn.get(3) or conn.setdefault(3, f())
Out[195]: 49

In [196]: conn.get(3) or conn.setdefault(3, f())
Out[196]: 49
```

NOTE: этот вариант будет работать правильно (как ожидается) только в том случае если `bool(dict_value) == True`. Т.е. для `connect_to(task.client_id) == 0` функция будет вызываться всегда, т.к. `bool(0) == False`.

---

Можно также воспользоваться кэширующим декоратором [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(1024)
def connect_to(client_id_key):
    """Connect to Amazon by token."""
    ...
    return connection
```

В таком варианте вызовы `connect_to(client_id_key)` будут кэшироваться и при повторном вызове `connect_to()` для того же `client_id_key` - результат будет браться из кэша.

Comment: а я и не знал, что так можно!!
думал уже абстрактный словарь плющить ))
я думал, что `conn.get(3) or conn.setdefault(3, f())`  возвращает только 1 или 0....
Снимаю шляпу!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, `x = a or b` - это короткий аналог `x = a if a else b`

Comment: Толковый мужик Гвидо!